# I have a MySQL query running from a NodeJS app which fails to pull data from the server

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express

I have this SQL query function, running in a NodeJS app which, before using docker was working fine.

```js
async function getAll(req) {
    var connection = await util.promisify(pool.getConnection.bind(pool))();
    console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadId}`);
    logger.customLogger.log('debug', 'await-connection', 'connection');
    var rows = await connection.query.bind(connection)('SELECT * FROM cam_features');
    var result;
    logger.customLogger.log('error', 'result:', result);
    Object.keys(rows).forEach(function (key) {
        result = rows[key];
        // console.log(result);
    });
    return result;
}
```

`pool` is defined here:

```js
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'sql',
    // host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'paragon',
    connectionLimit: 10
});
```

And the routing function which should call `getAll)` is:

```js
router.get('/product-page', (req, res) => {
    try {
        var data = getAll();
    } catch (error) {
        logger.customLogger.log('debug', 'route error', error);
    }
    res.send(data);
});
```

So far, since using docker, Ive been receiving nothing but empty objects back from the server.

The connection *is* happening, as I am getting a `connection.threadId` ID from the server.

Comment: May be there is no data inside container?

Comment: @YJR There is definitely data in the container, I have checked and spent the time ensuring the database is exactly as it was before docker.

Comment: Your processing function is calling `getAllData`, not `getAll`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, that was from trying it with the actual processing of the returned data, I will edit that. Even without, calling `getAll()` still returns an empty data object